# Left Joining on Multiple Tables with Timestamps

Tags: sql, oracle, join, left-join, multiple-tables

Ok SQL and Oracle gurus I have a somewhat complicated query that I'm trying to build.

Here is my current query:

```
select distinct person_info.person_name
     table2.value,
     table3.value,
     table4.value,
     table5.value
from person_info
    left join table2 on table2.person_name=person_info.person_name
    left join table3 on table3.person_name=person_info.person_name
    left join table4 on table4.person_name=person_info.person_name
    left join table5 on table5.person_name=person_info.person_name;
```

The primary key for every table is both the `person_name` and a `timestamp`. Now my problem is that if multiple instances of the same `person_name` exist in a table then I only want to `left join` on the most recent one. Does anyone know how to add this behavior to this query? I am using Oracle.

Thanks!

Comment: Are there start and end dates on each table, or just one timestamp column? Normally, where a record is only applicable for a specific date range, both start and end dates are recorded.

Comment: Just a timestamp column indicating when the record was inserted

Comment: @Mark Bannister - I disagree.  If you store both start and end timestamps, you risk both overlapping ranges and ranges without values.  However, if you store, for example, EFFECTIVE_DATE as a single fencepost, you then search for the greatest EFFECTIVE_DATE less than some date of interest.

Comment: @Adam Munsch, under some circumstances either overlapping ranges or ranges without values may be valid. In cases where neither is valid, the code used to generate the record should validate it accordingly. Strictly speaking, this (use of date ranges) could be regarded as a form of denormalisation; it's *much* harder to write SQL queries in instances like those above that use a single date value, rather than applicable ranges.

Comment: @Mark - I prefer not to rely on the application for data validation.  It may be harder to write such queries, but using a single effective_date fencepost guarantees that exclusive date ranges are exactly that.  Generally, this isn't denormalization as much as normalizing the data along a time dimension.  Most queries answer "what is X", not "what was X at time Y, regardless of what it is now."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
select distinct person_info.person_name
     t2.value,
     t3.value,
     t4.value,
     t5.value
from person_info
    left join (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by person_name order by timestamp_column desc) rowno from table2 t) t2 
         on t2.person_name=person_info.person_name and t2.rowno=1
    left join (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by person_name order by timestamp_column desc) rowno from table3 t) t3
         on t3.person_name=person_info.person_name and t3.rowno=1
    left join (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by person_name order by timestamp_column desc) rowno from table4 t) t4
         on t4.person_name=person_info.person_name and t4.rowno=1
    left join (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by person_name order by timestamp_column desc) rowno from table5 t) t5
         on t5.person_name=person_info.person_name and t5.rowno=1;
```

Comment: What is the `product_id` for? After the `partition by` clause?

Comment: Nevermind, I assume that it is supposed to be `person_name`. You might want to update your solution :) Thanks!